# Can't run Python script from anywhere, even after PATH variable was edited?

Tags: macbook-pro, python, path

I was trying to set up my Mac to run custom Python scripts from anywhere without having to type `python [script.py]` or the explicit file path.

The script is called "testscript". I put the script in my own bin directory (separate from `/usr/local/bin`), called `/User/Patrick/bin`, and added it to my path so when I type `echo $PATH` it comes up correctly like so:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/User/patrick/bin:/usr/local/go/bin`.
```

I already added the line `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the top of the file, I already did `chmod 700 testscript`, but I still can't call `testscript` from anywhere.
Have things changed since OSX Yosemite?

Comment: Case may matter, is it **P**atrick or **p**atrick? Also, what error message are you getting? Does running it via `~/bin/testscript` work?

Comment: No @patrix, OS X is case-insensitive.

Comment: Ah, probably, yes. But it's `/User**s**`, at least here.

Comment: @partix Yeah, thats right, certain UNIX tools are case sensitive.

Comment: @patrix Wow, that was it... I just noticed that on OSX it says "Users" instead of "User"... It works now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the script is executable.

`chmode +x filename`

Make sure the script has the appropriate shebang line at the top:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

Double check the path, it should be `/Users` (note the **s** at the end)

Answer (score 1):

## Which python are you targeting?

#### Did you install it with brew? It uses a different path.

`which python3` or `which python`

Choose the one you want

Copy that output

Paste it at the top of your python file

add a `#!` in front of that path so it looks something like

#### `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`

Make sure to change the file permissions

#### `chmod +x filename`

Put that file in a folder that is in your path

#### Not sure if your folder is in your path?

`echo $path`

#### How to add that folder to your path?

Find your path first

`echo $HOME`

If you are using bash or zsh you might have something like this

In `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` at the bottom of your file

`export PYTHON_UTILS="$HOME/code/python/utils"`

`export PATH="$PYTHON_UTILS:$PATH"`

Consider removing the `.py` from your file bc it is not needed in this case

Close and open your terminal, which is sourcing your file by its path

And now you should be able to treat your python file similar to a bash command

You don't need to use `python3 filename.py` to run the file, you can just use `filename`

#### From anywhere on your filesystem!